# Set Values on MultiIndex Dataframe based on Group aggregate value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a `MultiIndex` dataframe that looks like as follows:

```
In [1349]: print simple

         E
S C  R    
0 C0 R0  0
     R1  1
     R2  2
     R3  3
  C1 R0  1
     R1  2
     R2  3
     R3  4
  C2 R0  2
     R1  3
     R2  4
     R3  5
```

After aggregating the `E` column per the `C` column I get the following:

```
In [1352]: print simple.groupby(level=['S','C']).sum()

       E
S C     
0 C0   6
  C1  10
  C2  14
```

Essentially counting the number of `E` at the `C` index.  What I would like to do is to set the `E` value in the original dataframe to an arbitrary value depending on the result of the aggregation. For example, set all `E` to 0 for the group `(C)` if the aggregate is >= to some value.

in this instance since the total number of `E` for `C0` is 6, I would like to set the `E` to zero for any `C*` where the sum is >=6 to show something like:

```
In [1349]: print df

         E
S C  R    
0 C0 R0  0
     R1  0
     R2  0
     R3  0
  C1 R0  1
     R1  2
     R2  3
     R3  4
  C2 R0  2
     R1  3
     R2  4
     R3  5
```

I was able to do it using the code below,but it is not scalable and I am sure there must be a better way to do it:

```
s3 = (simple.groupby(level=['S','C']).aggregate(sum)< 7)
s3=s3[s3['E']==True]
simple_orig = simple.copy()
for idx in s3.index:
    simple.ix[idx]= 0
print simple
print simple_orig
             E
    S C  R    
    0 C0 R0  0
         R1  0
         R2  0
         R3  0
      C1 R0  1
         R1  2
         R2  3
         R3  4
      C2 R0  2
         R1  3
         R2  4
         R3  5
             E
    S C  R    
    0 C0 R0  0
         R1  0
         R2  0
         R3  0
      C1 R0  1
         R1  2
         R2  3
         R3  4
      C2 R0  2
         R1  3
         R2  4
         R3  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for creating boolean mask and then [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) like:

```
print simple
         E
S C  R    
0 C0 R0  0
     R1  1
     R2  2
     R3  3
  C1 R0  1
     R1  2
     R2  3
     R3  4
  C2 R0  2
     R1  3
     R2  4
     R3  5

mask = (simple.groupby(level=['S','C']).transform(sum)< 7)['E']
print mask
S  C   R 
0  C0  R0     True
       R1     True
       R2     True
       R3     True
   C1  R0    False
       R1    False
       R2    False
       R3    False
   C2  R0    False
       R1    False
       R2    False
       R3    False
Name: E, dtype: bool
```

```
simple.loc[mask, 'E'] = 0
print simple
         E
S C  R    
0 C0 R0  0
     R1  0
     R2  0
     R3  0
  C1 R0  1
     R1  2
     R2  3
     R3  4
  C2 R0  2
     R1  3
     R2  4
     R3  5
```

Comment: This indeed did it. I did not have a good understanding of the transform pattern which works because I believe it returns the same indexing as the original Dataframe. Thank you.